Elliptic $L^1$-estimate
I know a version of elliptic $L^1$-estimate: If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set and $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega),$ then we have $$ \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C\|\Delta f\|_{L^1(\Omega)}, $$
where $p \in \left[1,\frac{n}{n-2} \right)$ and $C=C(n,p,\Omega)>0.$ The proof use Green's representation theorem and Young's inequality. My question is: Can this constant $C$ be independent of $\Omega$? Is there any reference about it? Thank you for any insight!

Here's another reason why the answer is no. I think this is worth sharing because it illustrates an incredibly important theme in PDEs and functional analysis.
The answer is no because your inequality isn't scale invariant. Indeed, suppose that for all $u\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, we have that $$ \tag{$\ast$}\| u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C \| \Delta u \|_{L^1(\Omega)} $$ with $p\in \big [1 , \frac n {n-2} \big )$ and $C>0$ depending only on $n$ and $p$ (not $\Omega)$.
For $\lambda>0$, let $u_\lambda(x) = u(\lambda x)$ and $\Omega_\lambda = \{\lambda x \text{ s.t. } x\in \Omega\}$. Then, for any $u\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ arbitrary, \begin{align*}
\| u_\lambda\|_{L^p(\Omega_{\lambda^{-1}})}&=\lambda^{-\frac n p}\|
 u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\\
\| \Delta u_\lambda\|_{L^1(\Omega_{\lambda^{-1}})} &= \lambda^{2-n} \| \Delta u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}.
\end{align*} Hence, by ($\ast$), $$\|
 u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} =  \lambda^{\frac n p}\| u_\lambda\|_{L^p(\Omega_{\lambda^{-1}})}\leq C \lambda^{\frac n p}\| \Delta u_\lambda\|_{L^1(\Omega_{\lambda^{-1}})} =  \lambda^{\frac n p+2-n} \| \Delta u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$ Since $$ \frac n p+2-n >0$$ by the assumption on $p$, we may send $\lambda \to 0^+$ and obtain a contradiction.

Thank you very much!

The answer is negative. For any $M>0$, taking a radical cut-off function $\chi_M\in C_c^{\infty}(B_{M+1})$, $0\le \chi_M\le 1$, and $\chi_{M}(x)=1,\ {\rm if\ }|x|\le M$, $\chi_{M}(x)=0,\ {\rm if\ }|x|\ge M+1$. Define $f_M(x) = |x|^2\cdot \chi_{M}$,then
$$
  \|f_M\|_p^p\ge \int_{\{|x|\le M\}}|x|^{2p}dx = w_n\int_0^Mr^{2p+n-1}dr = C_0(n,p)M^{2p+n}.
$$
On the other hand, there holds
$$\begin{aligned}
  \|\Delta f_M\|_1^p \le& \bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|2n\chi_M| + |2x\cdot\nabla\chi_M| + |x|^2\cdot|\Delta\chi_M| dx\bigg)^p\\
  \le& C_1(n,p)(M^{np}+M^{np}+M^{(n+1)p})\\
  \le& C_2(n,p)M^{(n+1)p},
\end{aligned}$$
for $M>1$. If the $L^1$ elliptic estimate holds, then
$$
  M^{2p+n}\le C(n,p)M^{(n+1)p}\Rightarrow M^{n-(n-1)p}\le C(n,p).
$$
Clearly, if $n-(n-1)p>0$, that is, $p<\frac{n}{n-1}$ (Here $1\le p<\frac{n}{n-1}$), then it leads to a contradiction!
Remark. For $p\in[\frac{n}{n-1},\frac{n}{n-2})$, the constant $C(n,p,\Omega)$ may also depend on $\Omega$, but the function $f_M$ needs to be modified.

Thank you very much!
